# StageText very slow when opening

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, keyboard

When opening the soft keyboard on iOS devices using StageText the application halts and is unresponsive for a couple of seconds before the keyboard opens.

Are there any ways to avoid this?

/Karl

Comment: Some code would be nice

Comment: @David: The application halts even with the simpliest code like this: 

var st:StageText = new StageText();
st.viewPort = new Rectangle(10,10,200,20);
st.stage = main.stage;
st.assignFocus();